# Function Argument Type Grouping

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, typeguards

**Problem**

I have these two interfaces:

```
interface A {
   type: "a";
   aSpecificProp: number;
}
interface B {
   type: "b";
   bSpecificProp: boolean;
}
```

I am trying to implement a function `myFunc` that accepts two parameters `x, y` that must typed together (i.e. both of type A or both of type B).

**Attempt #1:**

```
myFunc = (x: A | B, y: A | B) => {};
```

The problem with this is that x and y do not necessarily have to both be of type A or of type B.

**Attempt 2**

```
type AorB = { x: A, y: A } | { x: B, y: B };
myFunc = (...{a, b}: AorB) => {};
```

If I use a typeguard inside `myFunc` to narrow down `x` to type A for example, `y` unfortunately will **not** also narrow down to type A.

**Attempt 3** - Generics as requested by @VLAZ

```
type myFuncDef<T> = (x: T, y: T) => void;
myFunc: myFuncDef<A | B> = (x, y) => {};
```

If I use a typeguard inside `myFunc` to narrow down `x` to type A for example, `y` still unfortunately will **not** also narrow down to type A.

**Clarification**

I understand that I can use a single parameter and specify it to be of type `AorB` and it will work fine. I also understand that I can use two type guards to narrow the types inside `myFunc`; however, I would like to know if there is a way to group these types such that I can pass two parameters to `myFunc` and only have to use **one** type guard to narrow down **both** parameters?

I have a strong inclination this problem can be solved with generics, but I think I am just doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Isn't this the job of generics, not type guards? `myFunc = <T>(x: T, y: T) => {};` Yes, you'd need to constrain `T` to be either `A` or `B` but point is, it's not a type guard solution.

Comment: Ah, I cannot believe I forgot about generics. Thanks!

Comment: You say you're trying to *implement* the function but I don't see any implementation body at all, just call signatures.  Could you show the problems with implementation?  The main problem is that `[A, A] | [B, B]` is not itself a discriminated union; it's more like a "nested discriminated union" of the type requested in [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758), but TS doesn't support those.  So if you want to do a type guard on that you'll have to write a custom type predicate function to do it.  Show your impl issues in a [mre] and I can maybe be more specific.

Comment: Like, it might be [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE5l3w) but I'd like to see what *you* plan to do with `x` and `y` inside the function.